# How to return back json data from script page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I had a json file **results.json** Which shown below. And I had a html file contain  some script. This is for retrieve data data. When I am enter into the html page which call a script function  `get_machFollow(que_script)` this function is for receive json file data. The function is works fine and which alert correct output, But after this function return some data to my **HTML** page.

My JSON file

```
{"mach_fol_4": {"match_l":
       ["7","8","99"],"attempts":"0","feedback_true":"You are right!",
  "feedback_false":"Sorry! wrong answer."}}
```

This is my script function. This function is works fine but I can't alert the return  value from HTML page. That shows undefined.

```
function get_machFollow(que_script)
{

        var return_var;
      $.getJSON('results.json', function(data) {
            return_var=data[que_script].match_r;    
            alert(return_var);//Working alert show correct output 
            return return_var;     
                 });

}
```

This is my html file

```
   <html>
    <head>
      <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.min.js'></script>
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
             var mach_follow_js;
             mach_follow_js=get_machFollow('mach_fol_4');
             alert(mach_follow_js);//Wrong output
         });
   </head>
    <body>
      <p>Hello world</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `$.getJson` is an asynchronous call so when you call `get_matchFollow` and try to alert the response in next line, response from ajax has not come.That's why it is coming as undefined

Comment: Give me an idea for get values from this $.getJson

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways by which you can do it. One of them is **pass a callback handler** to your method which will be called when you get the response. Try this:

```
function get_machFollow(que_script, sCallback)
{
      var return_var;
      $.getJSON('results.json', function(data) {
            return_var=data[que_script].match_r;    
            alert(return_var);//Working alert show correct output 
            sCallback.call(null /* context */, return_var);      
       });

}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var mach_follow_js;
    get_machFollow('mach_fol_4', function(output) {
        alert(output);
        match_follow_js = output;
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

are you intending return return_var; to be inside the get_machFollow scope, because right now its inside the jquery function scope and will not return value to the main page

Comment: Then how can I get this values? I need a solution not advice.

Comment: I have not tried this with jquery but check what the $.getJSON method is returning if its not void, you might be able to assign return_var=  $.getJSON..., but keep the return in the getJSON and add a new one to the outer function

Comment: $.getJSON return some useless objects for show the function is ready.

Answer (score 1):

Here below JSON data fetched by AJAX. It passing JSON Data Object in Alert.
You can use it as you want. also can Iterate data using for loop or $.each function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var mach_follow_js;
    // mach_follow_js=get_machFollow('mach_fol_4');

    //JSON Data Fetched by AJAX
    $.ajax('results.json',{
        type:'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        jsonCallback: 'successCallback',               
        async: true,
        beforeSend: function () {
        //if you want to show loader
    },
    complete: function () {
        //hide loader after download data
    },
    success: function (resultJSON) {                                       
        mach_follow_js = resultJSON;        // assigning to Global variable ProductResult                   
        alert(mach_follow_js);
        console.log(mach_follow_js);
    },
    error: function (request, error) {
        alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');//error
    }
    })                              

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax callback function  `$.getJSON()` is actually an ajax function. So you need to apply callback to perform this action.